# firebase replaced my data when restarting my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app will generate a gameKey everytime user logged in and clicked "start game" button. Variable "gameKey" is generated by the following code, and then I will save data under the gameKey. The problem is, whenever I restart my app, the Firebase replaced the whole data tree with a new gameKey generated.

What I would like to do is to generate a new gameKey without overwriting the old data every time when my app runs. It would be so glad if anyone can point out my problem, thanks so much!

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    UserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference currentUserId = database.getReference("user").child(UserId);

    gameKey = currentUserId.child("gameinfo").push().getKey();

    Map<String, Object> game = new HashMap<>();
    game.put(gameKey, new Game(tv_player1name.getText().toString(), tv_player2name.getText().toString(), tv_player3name.getText().toString(), tv_playerMename.getText().toString(), gameMode, gameDate ));
    currentUserId.child("gameInfo").updateChildren(game);

Firebase Data:
  - user
      - 5xGKRXeHgThQy70lduPEp3mosTj1   (UID)
            - gameInfo
                  -LLV0H0ZJwYT5M42Obfb
                       gameDate: "20180903_232015"      
                       gameType: "HKMJ"
                       player1name: "peter"
                       player2name: "jenny"
                       player3name: "john"
                       player4name: "wilson"

     *This is the gameKey generated: "LLV0H0ZJwYT5M42Obfb"
```

This is the code after your suggestions:

```
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference currentUserId = database.getReference("user").child(UserId);
  currentUserId.setValue(new User(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), UserPic));
  gameKey = currentUserId.child("gameinfo").push().getKey();

  Map<String, Object> game = new HashMap<>();

  game.put(gameKey, new Game(tv_player1name.getText().toString(), tv_player2name.getText().toString(), tv_player3name.getText().toString(), tv_playerMename.getText().toString(), gameMode, gameDate )); 

  currentUserId.child("gameInfo").child(gameKey).updateChildren(game);
```

In addition, I tried to replace this line

```
 game.put(gameKey, new Game(tv_player1name.getText().toString(), tv_player2name.getText().toString(), tv_player3name.getText().toString(), tv_playerMename.getText().toString(), gameMode, gameDate ));
```

with this line, same result

```
 Game game = new Game(tv_player1name.getText().toString(), tv_player2name.getText().toString(), tv_player3name.getText().toString(), tv_playerMename.getText().toString(), gameMode, gameDate );
```

Appreciate so much for the help!

[Firebase ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4o3x.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
currentUserId.child("gameInfo").updateChildren(game);
```

to

```
currentUserId.child("gameInfo").child(gameKey).updateChildren(game);
```

You are basically generating a random key but you aren't using it at all. So you need to pass the `gameKey` to the `child()` method as seen in my above code.

**Edit:** So solve the entire update process, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = rootRef.child("user").child(uid).child("gameInfo");
String key = gameInfoRef.push().getKey();
Map<String, Object> game = new HashMap<>();
game.put("player1name", tv_player1name.getText().toString());
game.put("player2name", tv_player2name.getText().toString());
game.put("player3name", tv_player3name.getText().toString());
game.put("playerMename", tv_playerMename.getText().toString());
game.put("gameMode", gameMode);
game.put("gameDate", gameDate);
gameInfoRef.child(key).updateChildren(game);
```

Comment: Hi Wilson! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your solution, but it is not working, still the same old problem. Every time re launching the app will replace the old gameKey info with new gameKey info. Sign...

Comment: Even if you are using `.child(gameKey)`? Using this extra child can provide at least another kind of error. Can you please paste here the entire error?

Comment: Yes, I used .child(gameKey).
Since it produce no error at all, just firebase replacing old data, so I don't know how to show you the error, but I would like to attach the firebase screencap here, but seems there's no image able to attach here. 
In short, the old gameKey data will turn red and got deleted while the new gameKey data appears to be green and replaced the red data...

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: Edited the post with image link, hope it helps, please let me know what else do you need, thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, this is the exact thing that was talking about. Please add the exact code that you using when getting this problem. Is the one in your question?

Comment: final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference currentUserId=database.getReference("user").child(UserId);
currentUserId.setValue(new User(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), UserPic));
gameKey = currentUserId.child("gameinfo").push().getKey();

Map<String, Object> game = new HashMap<>();
game.put(gameKey, new Game(tv_player1name.getText().toString(), tv_player2name.getText().toString(), tv_player3name.getText().toString(), tv_playerMename.getText().toString(), gameMode, gameDate ));
currentUserId.child("gameInfo").child(gameKey).updateChildren(game);

Comment: Please add it to your question to be properly formatted. I cannot understand it in this way.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope the field names are correct (`player1name`, `player2name` and so on ).

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THank you sooo much!!!! Appreciate it Bro!!! I can finally carry on my project now T_T thanks!!!!

Comment: May I know, does it mean I should update the value one at a time instead of using Game() constructer? or may be my Game() constructer somehow wrote in the wrong way?

Comment: You can update either by using a Map or the game object.